# CursorAdapter does not seem to have a function to set the cursor

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to create a custom `CursorAdapter`. I have setup a database which is in the `DBAdapter` class. I have:

```
public class ExampleCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public ExampleCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView summary = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        summary.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.question)));
    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.more_results, parent, false);
        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;
    }

}
```

I have a detailed feedback class where I am creating an instance of `ExampleCursorAdapter`. The problem I am having is there doesn't seem to be anything to set the `CursorAdapter`.

```
     public class DetailedFeedback extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
    ExampleCursorAdapter adapter = new ExampleCursorAdapter(this, c);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

I am not sure if this is the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom adapter constructor is:

```
public ExampleCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}
```

and when you instantiate it you set a `null` `Context` and a `null` `Cursor`. Set the cursor where you instantiate the adapter:

```
Cursor c = //.. retrieve a cursor with results from the database
ExampleCursorAdapter adapter = new ExampleCursorAdapter(this, c);
```

You also have the method [`changeCursor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29).

Comment: do i make it equal to a column that i am trying to return

Comment: @Alexander Do you know how to make a query on a database? You return a cursor after you make a query to the database for the columns `_id` and `DBAdapter.question`.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand what i am meant to assign to the cursor

Comment: @Alexander When you make a query to the database like : `SELECT FROM some_table...` you'll get back a `Cursor` object and that cursor you'll use with your adapter. If you don't understand this you should follow some tutorials about database interactions in android and how to manipulate a `Cursor` with results.

Comment: thanks i will have a look at some tutorials do you know any off the top of your head

Comment: @Alexander Check this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html and also see the other tutorials on that site(ignore the `ContentProvider` part). You could also check the official android developer site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html .

Answer (score 0):

Try SimpleCursorAdapter for database entries.
[SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)